# How do I display IE7 specific content?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I've been trying to display an IE7 specific tag but it doesn't seem to be working. I know that this should be really straightforward, so hopefully someone will be able to help. Here's my code:

```
<!--[if IE 7]> <div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?= FB_URL; ?>" data-num-posts="2" data-width="700"></div> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 7]><!--> <div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?= FB_URL; ?>" data-num-posts="8" data-width="700"></div> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: specifically, what's different here for IE7? It looks like just the `num-posts` value is different? I can think of better ways to do this, but as much as anything else I'm curious about *why* you'd want to do this?

Answer (score -1):

please you use these techniques, as follows. I give some examples that implement your projects:

1. The css method's supported in all the browsers.

   .test
      {
        font-color:red;
      }
2. This method only applies in the ie7 browser:

   .test
      {
        *font-color:red;
      }
3. This method only applies in the ie7 and ie8 browser:

   .test
      {
        font-color:red\9;
      }

Follow those techniques and you get the result.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, however I didn't want to style things depending on the browser but display browser specific content.